# git workflow for merging new branch and how to stop auto-merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

The setup of my repositories is like this:

A web server named LIVE
A server acting as central repo with a bare clone from LIVE, named REPO
A test web server named TEST with a clone from REPO (aka the same files as LIVE)
Egit with eclipse for localhost development and debugging.

If i want to add a new feature to my site i thought i can use a workflow like this..
@LIVE: git push #get the latest files from LIVE server to REPO
@eclipse: "fetch from upstream" #get the latest files from REPO to ECLIPSE
now i create a new branch called "mynewfeature" and when i'm done:
@eclipse: "push to upstream" #push the new branch to REPO
@TEST: git fetch
**how can i check here which files(only filenames) will change with merge?

How can i check which files are conflicting before merging?**
@TEST: git merge origin/mynewfeature #apply my new feature
now if everything is ok i do:
@LIVE: git fetch #get the new feature to LIVE server
@LIVE: git merge origin/mynewfeature

Is this workflow correct?

My major problem now is conflicts..
with SVN if i had a confict durring update i was asked which file i wanted, with git i get an "auto-merge" which breaks my PHP files.
Can i stop auto-merge when merging files?

Comment: Consider what happens if the first time you do a merge (on TEST), you get merge conflicts that you have to resolve manually. How would this affect the remainder of your workflow? You certainly can't resolve the merge conflicts on LIVE because, well, it's live.

Answer (score 0):

Normally what you will do is do the merge on your *local* development system.

- pull from REPO
- branch for `mynewfeature`
- develop locally
- push branch to REPO
- pull `mynewfeature` branch to TEST
- if all goes well...
- *in your development system*, merge `mynewfeature` into `master`
- push `master` to REPO
- pull `master` to TEST, do a final check of everything post-merge
- pull `master` to LIVE

The only time you're doing a merge here is in your development system. You resolve any conflicts locally using the usual procedure for doing so. After you push the result of the merge back to `master`, nobody else has to repeat the merge procedure you just did.

Comment: doing a merge at localhost sounds good to me, but what if, while i'm developing a file from LIVE, that change? will i get a conflict again?
And if i had to resolve the conflict at my local repo wouldn't that conflict re-appear when i make a pull master to LIVE?

Comment: Yes, you may get merge conflicts if two people change the same part of the same file at the same time. I would recommend a good book such as [Pro Git](http://progit.org) (available for free) which describes all of this in detail.

Comment: Hi Greg, Sorry for the delay..
I checked Pro Git but i stil didnt found the info i was looking for..
Is there an equilavent to "svn status --show-updates" command for git? (look at the bottom http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/svn/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)
This will answer my first questions in bold..